# Lambda not work with filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I tried to print all the prime number less than 100 with flowing code:

```
def _odd_iter():
    n=1
    while True:
        n=n+2
        yield n

def _not_divisible(n):
    return lambda x: x % n > 0    

def primes():
    yield 2
    it = _odd_iter()
    while True:
            n=next(it)
            yield n
            it = filter(_not_divisible(n),it)

for n in primes():
    if n<100:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

And it works fine.
But after I change the `_not_divisible` function into lambda, it seems not work:

```
def _odd_iter():
    n=1
    while True:
        n=n+2
        yield n

def primes():
    yield 2
    it = _odd_iter()
    while True:
            n=next(it)
            yield n
            it = filter(lambda x:x%n>0,it)

for n in primes():
    if n<100:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

The result shows that the filter has dropped nothing.

Why doesn't it works with lambda?

Comment: You are running into capture rules with python. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python

Comment: @AnilRedshift Was hoping someone would find a good existing question for this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `n` which is used within the lambda will always refer to the local value. If `n` changes in the surrounding context, it will also do so within the lambda*. If you want to capture the current value, you can use this instead:

```
it = filter(lambda x, n=n: x % n > 0, it)
```

---

*It's probably easier to understand if you think of the context as a dictionary in which local variables are stored and looked up and which always stays the same. Explicitly written that way your `primes()` function would look like this:

```
def primes():
    ctx = {}
    yield 2
    ctx['it'] = _odd_iter()
    while True:
            ctx['n'] = next(ctx['it'])
            yield ctx['n']
            ctx['it'] = filter(lambda x: x % ctx['n'] > 0, ctx['it'])
```

Now it should be clear that when values in `ctx` change, that changes will also be picked up within the lambda. Basically the same also happens without the `ctx` dict, and that is what often leads to misunderstandings.

Comment: I am sorry I do not get the point of the sentence: If `n` changes, it will also within the lambda. Does it means that although the var name `n` in function `primes` points to a new memory address containing a new value, the var name `n` in the lambda still points to the origin address? So, the `n` in the lambda does not change.

Comment: @TJM - tried to explain it a little better, hope that helps